# Modelica Iteration Problems

Tags: iteration, modelica

I am very new to Modelica and mainly have one big problem:
If I use comparisons like e.g. *greater as threshold*, I don't get the simulation to finish from time to time. The thing is, this doesn't happen always. But if it does, I get the following error message:
"Fix point iteration did not converge at time : xxx"

I already fixed this problem from once with using a hysteresis instead of the "hard" comparison. Do I really have to do this in every case I'll need it? Or does somebody have another idea or solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You do not need to add hysteresis for every comparison you make.  The issue is when you have a comparison that triggers a behavior change **and** that behavior change drives you back toward the other behavior.

You can find more about the topic of events, discrete behavior and hysteresis in [Modelica by Example](http://book.xogeny.com/behavior/discrete/hysteresis/).

Comment: Ok, thank you so far. I think I get at least the basic idea.  So by right now I've implemented the following for my hysteresis, but for some reason it doesn't change the output value (y; boolean). 
It must be some quite simple mistake which I don't get over here.

`initial equation
  y = if u1>=u2 then true else false;

equation
  b = if y then u1 else u2;
  s = if y then u2 else u1;
  trig = s+hyst-b;

algorithm
  when trig<=0 then
    y := if pre(y) then false else true;
  end when;`

Comment: I am sorry, but for some reason I do not even manage to format a comment.

Comment: You are relying too much on `if`.  Read the documentation I linked to and/or use the hysteresis block in the Modelica Standard Library.

Answer (score 2):

You could encapsulate the hysteresis comparison inside a function and use that everywhere.

Comment: Are you sure?  Hysteresis requires an additional state. I don't see how you could get that with a function.  However, there is a **block** in the MSL for hysteresis.

Comment: My bad, i was talking about a realCompare function that does the comparison with an epsilon.